# I can't delete the space in my edit profile form

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

I've been working on a project and I have everything functional on the page, minus one little set back. When I open the edit profile form there is 28 blank spaces before the name and title, while there is also 24 spaces after. If I delete all the text and spaces then my placeholder text will appear in the correct spot. My add element popup works with no issues. I have been combing over my code to see if I have any extra spaces that could be doing this and I still can't find anything. Any help would be appreciated.

https://gbolton1989.github.io/web_project_4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in your javascript file `index.js`

```
editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!editProfileModalWindow.classList.contains("popup_is")) {
        nameInput.value = profileName.textContent;
        aboutInput.value = profileSubname.textContent;
    }
    toggleModalWindow(editProfileModalWindow);
})
```

The `textContent` property gets the content of all elements, not just the text (see more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#:%7E:text=textContent%20gets%20the%20content%20of,text%20of%20%E2%80%9Chidden%E2%80%9D%20elements.)). Because your element has a `<h1>` element child, you are getting the extra space.

To fix this, you can either:

1. Use the `innerText` property instead of `textContent` which only gets the human readable text
2. Make the `profileName` variable refer to the `h1` element rather than it's parent. Then `textContent` will work properly

Examples:

```
editButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (!editProfileModalWindow.classList.contains("popup_is")) {
        nameInput.value = profileName.innerText;
        // or
        // nameInput.value = profileName.children[0].textContent
        aboutInput.value = profileSubname.innerText;
    }
    toggleModalWindow(editProfileModalWindow);
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That did it!